# prove $\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{a+2}{b+2}\le \sum_\text{cyc}\frac{a}{b}$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof, rearrangement-inequality

> Prove if $a,b,c$ are positive $$\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{a+2}{b+2}\le \sum_\text{cyc}\frac{a}{b}$$

**My proof**:After rearranging we have to prove $$\sum_\text{cyc} \frac{b}{b^2+2b} \le \sum_\text{cyc} \frac{a}{b^2+2b}$$

As inequality is cyclic:

let $a\ge b\ge c$ then $$\frac{1}{a^2+2a}\le \frac{1}{b^2+2b}\le \frac{1}{c^2+2c}$$.The rest follows by **rearrangement inequality**.

The case $a\ge c\ge b$ is analogous.

Thus Proved!

Is it correct?...And any other alternative ways possible?

Comment: Alternatives here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1525182p9139174

Comment: Sorry for the first proof ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is nice and right.

Another way.

Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}-1\geq\frac{a+2}{b+2}+\frac{b+2}{a+2}-2+\frac{c+2}{a+2}-\frac{b+2}{a+2}+\frac{b+2}{c+2}-1$$ or
$$\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+\frac{(c-a)(c-b)}{ac}\geq\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+2)(b+2)}+\frac{(c-a)(c-b)}{(a+2)(c+2)},$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Your application of rearrangement is correct, in either case, $(a, b, c)$ and $(a^2+a, b^2+b, c^2+c)$ are similarly ordered, so
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{a^2+2a} \leqslant \sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{b^2+2b}$$

---

For another way, which generalises, consider
$$f(x) = \sum_{cyc} \frac{a+x}{b+x}, \quad f'(x) = \sum_{cyc} \frac{b-a}{(b+x)^2} = \sum_{cyc} \frac{b}{(b+x)^2} - \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(b+x)^2} \leqslant  0$$
again by Rearrangement.  Hence $f$ is decreasing, and $f(0) \geqslant f(2)$

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the first non-obvious proof and I give you a refinement

Hint :$a\geq b \geq c$

First prove that :

$$\frac{2(x-y)}{x+y+y^2}\leq \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x+2}{y+2}\quad (1)$$

For that multiply by $y(y+2)(x+y+y^2)$ , put in factor and it becomes :

$$2(x-y)^2\geq 0$$

Apply $(1)$ for $(a,b)$,$(b,c)$,$(c,a)$

Now we need to show :

$$\frac{2(a-b)}{a+b+b^2}+\frac{2(b-c)}{b+c+c^2}+\frac{2(c-a)}{a+c+a^2}\geq 0$$

Now introducing $f(c)$

$$\frac{2(b-c)}{b+c+c^2}+\frac{2(c-a)}{a+c+a^2}=f(c)$$

Using derivatives prove that $f(c)$ is decreasing when $c$ increases .

Now we put $b=c$ and the inequality becomes :

$$\frac{2(a-b)}{a+b+b^2}+\frac{2(b-a)}{a+b+a^2}\geq 0$$

Wich is obvious with the condition $a\geq b \geq c $

Comment: @Erik Satie   How you want to use SOS here? Explain please.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative proof.
We need to prove that
$$
\frac{a}{b} + 
\frac{b}{c} + 
\frac{c}{a} \geqslant 
\frac{a + 2}{b + 2} + 
\frac{b + 2}{c + 2} + 
\frac{c + 2}{a + 2}
$$
Here we can write this inequality in $2$ forms:
$$
\frac{c}{a} - 
\frac{c + 2}{a + 2} \geqslant
\frac{a + 2}{b + 2} - 
\frac{a}{b} +
\frac{b + 2}{c + 2} - 
\frac{b}{c} 
$$
$$
\frac{c - a}{a^2 + 2a} = 
\frac{b - a}{a^2 + 2a} + \frac{c - b}{a^2 + 2a}
\geqslant 
\frac{b - a}{b^2 + 2b} + 
\frac{c - b}{c^2 + 2c}
$$
And
$$
\frac{b}{c} - \frac{b + 2}{c + 2} + 
\frac{c}{a} - \frac{c + 2}{a + 2} \geqslant
\frac{a + 2}{b + 2} - \frac{a}{b}
$$
$$
\frac{b - c}{c^2 + 2c} + 
\frac{c - a}{a^2 + 2a} \geqslant
\frac{b - a}{b^2 - 2b}
$$
Let $\min{(a,b,c)} = a$.

**Case I**: $c\geqslant b\geqslant a$: Write inequality in the first form.

**Case II**: $b\geqslant c\geqslant a$: Write inequality in the second form.

Comment: nice(+1) but i am getting something different in your second step,are you sure

Comment: Oh yeah! The proof is faulty, I am sorry.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I have corrected it. Please take a look.

Comment: very neat! thanks!

Comment: Actually its a bit similar to the proof of rearrangement inequality,still it is good

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore You are welcome. Yes it is partially similar to your proof and to Michael Rozenberg's proof, but still different!